# Why is $ |\exp(ia)-\exp(ia + ib)+ib| \leq |1-\exp(ib) + ib| + |b||1-\exp(ia)|$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

I'm reading a proof and it uses the following inequality, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

$$|\exp(ia)-\exp(ia + ib)+ib| \leq |1-\exp(ib) + ib| + |b||1-\exp(ia)|$$

I tried to use the triangle inequality but could not prove it.

Comment: Have you tried raising to a power and then applying the triangle inequality?

Comment: What do you mean with raising to a power? What power?

Comment: I'm silly, never mind, sorry! I apologise, I was thinking of sth different.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this as
$$
|\exp(ia)-\exp(ia + ib)+ib| \leq |1-\exp(ib) + ib| + |b||1-\exp(ia)|\\
\leftrightarrow\\
|- (1-\exp(ia))(1-\exp(ib)) + 1-\exp(ib)+ib| \leq |1-\exp(ib) + ib| + |b||1-\exp(ia)|\\
$$
Using $x = (1-\exp(ia))(1-\exp(ib)) $, $y=1-\exp(ib)+ib$ and $|-x +y| \le |x| + |y|$

leaves to show 
$$
|1-\exp(ia)||1-\exp(ib)| + |1-\exp(ib)+ib| \leq |1-\exp(ib) + ib| + |b||1-\exp(ia)|\\
$$
from which remains
$$
|1-\exp(ib)| \leq  |b|
$$
Square it:
$$
2 - 2 \cos(b) = (1-\exp(ib))(1-\exp(-ib)) = |1-\exp(ib)|^2 \leq  b^2
$$
which is 
$$
\cos(b) \ge 1 - \frac12 b^2 
$$
and this holds true for the cosine function. $\qquad \Box$

Comment: Thanks. It is completely clear!